# migration steps change, up and down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

My question is really simple. I created this migration file and my mobile column didn't change BUT `def change` was created. Is it because rails ignored `def up` and `def down`? if so why?

```
def change
  add_column :posts, :address, :string
end


def up
 execute 'ALTER TABLE posts ALTER COLUMN mobile TYPE integer USING (mobile::integer)'
end

def down
  execute 'ALTER TABLE posts ALTER COLUMN mobile TYPE text USING (mobile::text)'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails will not run both the change and up methods by design thus ignoring everything after the change method.  When you need to run some specific logic like in your Up and Down methods you have two choices.  You can either put the stuff in your change method into the up and down methods or you can put the Up and Down stuff into the change method.    If you want to do this the "Rails4" way you should use `change` and the `reversible` method to get what you need:

```
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration

 def change
    add_column :posts, :address, :string

    reversible do |change|
      change.up do
       execute 'ALTER TABLE posts ALTER COLUMN mobile TYPE integer USING (mobile::integer)'
      end

      change.down do
        execute 'ALTER TABLE posts ALTER COLUMN mobile TYPE text USING (mobile::text)'
      end
    end
  end
```